# Why I can't access to dblog?

Tags: log-messages

Why I can't access "Recent log messages" (via `/admin/reports/dblog`)?

It's not listed in the Admin Menu. And when I try to get there directly (via `/admin/reports/dblog`), I only see the "Reports", as shown via `/admin/reports`.

I've installed Drupal 7.15 with the OpenPublish Profile.

What could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: check whether "dblog" module is enabled

Comment: Ooooook.... Thanks! The module's name is "Database logging".

Comment: Yes of course "database logging" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, Check whether "Database logging" module is enabled in your modules list.